# Itunes Connect Invalid Binary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store, itunes

I submitted my app in the App Store. First I validated it, and turns out successful. Then I submitted it and succesfully uploaded to iTunes Connect. After a minute, it says that the file is Invalid binary. I am uploading an update of an existing app which is already published in the App Store. (previous version uploaded by other developer). I tried every solution that I found in google search but no luck.

Comment: I am not an iOS developer, but could it be that Apple has certificates in place to prevent a developer from replacing someone else's app with their own, since that would be a security risk?

Answer (score 3):

**Just for information.**

Today I faced the same problem of `Invalid Binary` while uploading new version of existing application.
I got following email from apple

> iPhone 5 Optimization Requirement - Your binary is not optimized for
>   iPhone 5. As of May 1, all      new iPhone apps and app updates
>   submitted must support the 4-inch display on iPhone 5. All apps must
>   include a launch image with the -568h size modifier immediately
>   following the  portion of the launch image's filename.
>   Launch images must be PNG files and located at the top-level of your
>   bundle, or provided within each .lproj folder if you localize your
>   launch images. Learn more about iPhone 5 support and app launch images
>   by reviewing the iOS Human Interface Guidelines and iOS App
>   Programming Guide.
>
> Once these issues have been corrected, go to the Version Details page
>   and click "Ready to Upload Binary." Continue through the submission
>   process until the app status is "Waiting for Upload." You can then
>   deliver the corrected binary.

**Solution:**

1. Added 4inch app screen shots in iTunesconnect meta data
2. Added Default-568h@2x.png image in my application for iPhone 5

After these changes application successfully submitted.

Answer (score 1):

**Need to add arm64**

I faced the same problem of Invalid Binary while uploading new version of existing application.

The reason are from **February 2015 itself we need to Add arm64** to our app. i added this then my app successfully upload to app store.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the provisioning you made for the itunes store are correct with your application.
Remove the old binary which has been rejected then add the new one.
If you can do try to make fresh provisioning and also check in the xcode as well.
And do check the mode,is that debug or distribution as you need to make the build for distribution.
Hope it man help you.

Cheers
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

You cannot submit an app that uses the same bundle ID or the same app name of any app (even the "same" one) submitted by another developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have choosen "App Store" as distribution method in distribution provisioning profile, not "Ad Hoc".

Answer (score 0):

```
I have faced this issue many times.My app got passed validation and submitted     
successfully to iTunes Connect.But It shows invalid binary in prerelease 
options.I saw one awesome post in Apple discussions and finally solved my 
issue.App bundle id was changed in config file of my web app.I have changed 
old bundle id in config.xml and app uploaded for review.
```

Comment: This solution useful for ones who are submitting web apps for Apple review.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the Application Loader under /Developer/Applications/Utilities. Make sure you have created a New App in iTunesConnect...under Manage Applications, select the application you are going to create an update for... when that loads on the right you will see Add a New Update.

Comment: Also... how are you creating your .ipa file?

Comment: thanks for reposnding :) I am upgrading the previous app to the new version. I am using Xcode 4.0, Product > Archieve > Validate > Submit    thats how I do it.

Comment: If you do Archive > Share > you can save it as an iPA then use that file to submit via Application Loader (its an app on your mac already that comes with XCode). I have had better luck with that when the submit gives me issues.